# Javascript/RegEx: Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I know similar questions are available but I could not find this case.

CASE 1: `'a,b,c,d,e'`

OUTPUT: `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`

CASE 2: `'a,b,"c,d", e'`

OUTPUT: `["a", "b", "c,d", "e"]`

CASE 3: `'a,,"c,d", e'`

OUTPUT: `["a", "", "c,d", "e"]`

RegEx that I tried: `(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)`

RegEx Link: https://regex101.com/r/xImG4i/1

This regex works well with CASE1 and CASE2 But is failing for CASE3.
Insead it works for

`'a, ,"c,d", e'`, giving output as `["a", " ", "c,d", "e"]`

which is also fine but need to work for CASE3 also.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're parsing a CSV file, also be aware that quotes are typically escaped by doubling them. So `a,b,"c""d"` should be parsed as `['a', 'b', 'c"d']`. Better to just use an existing CSV parsing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take optional whitespace chars between 2 comma's if a lookbehind is supported.

```
"[^"]*"|[^\s,'"]+(?:\s+[^\s,'"]+)*|(?<=,)\s*(?=,)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXOmWc/2)

```js
const regex = /"[^"]*"|[^\s,'"]+(?:\s+[^\s,'"]+)*|(?<=,)\s*(?=,)/g;

[
  `'a,b,c,d,e'`,
  `'a,b,"c,d", e'`,
  `'a,,"c,d", e'`,
  ` xz a,, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h`,
  `'a, ,"c,d", e'`,
].forEach(s => 
  console.log(s.match(regex))
)
```

If you don't want the double quotes you can use a capture group with matchAll and check for the group in the callback.

```js
const regex = /"([^"]*)"|[^\s,'"]+(?:\s+[^\s,'"]+)*|(?<=,)\s*(?=,)/g;

[
  `'a,b,c,d,e'`,
  `'a,b,"c,d", e'`,
  `'a,,"c,d", e'`,
  ` xz a,, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h`,
  `'a, ,"c,d", e'`,
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1] ? m[1] : m[0]))
)
```

Comment: That's amazing. But for ` xz a,, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h` the output is incorrect. It separated xz and a. It should have been `"xz a"`

Comment: @AayushJain Try it with the updated answer.

Comment: Wanted to know is there a way we have remove double quotes from resulting array? like `["a"," ","c,d","e"]` instead of `["a", " ", "\"c,d\"", "e"]`

Comment: @AayushJain I have added another example to leave out the double quotes in the result.

Comment: But removing double quotes doesn't work with the first regex you provided. the second one seems to be the old one.

Comment: Could you please provide how to achieve this with the first regex?

Comment: @AayushJain Ah I copied the wrong one. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution that uses a regex for splitting instead of matching:

```bash
/,\s*(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/
```

This regex will split on comma followed by optional spaces if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes after comma+space.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UNkUuw/1)

**Code Sample:**

```js
const re = /,\s*(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/;

[
  `a,b,"c,d", e`,
  `a,,"c,d", e`,
  ` xz a,, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h`,
  `a, ,"c,d", e`,
].forEach(s => {
  tok = s.split(re);
  tok.forEach((e, i) => tok[i] = e.replace(/^"|"$/g, ''))
  
  console.log(s, '::', tok);
})
```

Comment: That's awesome @anubhava. But can we also remove the double quotes as well from the resulting array? Like `["a"," ","c,d","e"]` instead of `["a", " ", "\"c,d\"", "e"]`

Comment: check my updated answer for that